# Rails 6: conditional link asset in manifest.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

In my Rails 6 application that uses `grape_swagger_rails`, the Swagger UI should only be available in specific environments.

But their Readme asks to to modify `manifest.js` which is applied across all environments. I tried renaming it to `manifest.js.erb` and using Ruby code to make the `link` statement conditional but as it turns out, ERB is not supported there.

Is there a way to conditionally include assets in the manifest based on the Rails environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use two manifest files and include them conditionally like shown below:

```
  <% if X %>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifestX.json">
  <% else %>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <% end %>
```